# Is there any law requiring public school to notify parents of Covid contact?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, school, new-mexico

I have a son attending a public school. I learned from unofficial channels that a classmate is quarantining for COVID, someone my son was in regular contact with throughout the day. The teachers are saying they are forced to keep quiet about it, not allowed to tell anyone about the case.

I understand for privacy, they cannot release the name, but not releasing details of an outbreak in the same classroom seems careless.

Are there any laws requiring notifying of COVID cases?

Comment: What state are you in?

Comment: @bdb484 added a state tag.